# Cannot import Aer from Qiskit 0.7

Tags: python, python-import, qiskit

I've created a new virtual environment in Anaconda and installed several packages using pip (namely, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, qiskit and maybe 1 or 2 more). I open the interpreter and try to import a module from Qiskit:

```
from qiskit import Aer
```

As a result, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer'`. My understanding is that either Qiskit 0.7 has a different structure of the modules (which I can't find anywhere in the documentation) or that my setup has a conflict of some kind. How do I know what is the case and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**: I have a dual boot system. The problem occurs on Anaconda on Windows 10, but doesn't on Ubuntu 18 on pure Python. So I think it has to be something with Anaconda rather than Qiskit.

**EDIT 2**: I have made a clean install of Python (without Anaconda) and the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys! I barely even remember how I got out of this issue :( I think I raised an issue on qiskit's github page, and they suggested rebuilding it from source. I decided not to bother and keep doing everything on Linux.

Now, though, the question must be obsolete at all because Qiskit's current version is much higher than 0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, I also had the same issue: Anaconda 3 on Windows 10. I later had the same trouble on a travis CI python 3.5 & 3.6 build image. For both I had a similar yet different solution. The similarity lies in the fact that it seems to be a missing dependency. The code of the simulator is written in C++ or maybe now Cython. So they use some dependencies that your setup may not have.
This is where the similarities ended. What I did:

## Windows 10 / Anaconda setup

With the dependency walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/ I found out that the openblas.dll is missing as dependency. Interesting enough, in the legacy simulators the qiskit team provided one. So you could either use this one or download (and rename!!) the latest binary from https://www.openblas.net/. Then copy it into your site-packages folder. You know you got the right folder when you find files with the names of the sort

- unitary_controller_wrapper.pyd
- statevector_controller_wrapper.pyd
- qasm_controller_wrapper.pyd

## Travis CI python >= 3.5 image

Here on the other hand I was at loss with the same explanation (and solution), so I looked into qiskit-aer repository's `.travis` setup. Here you see, that they use (among other directives)
 - `sudo apt-get -y install g++-7`
 - `sudo apt-get -y install libopenblas-dev`
I used this for my travis CI and - voilà - it works. Prior to this I used `ldd` and `readelf` and it pointed to some library that I don't recall but it seems like qiskit-aer depends on it and you get this with a more recent version of g++.

I wonder if this will solve your issues.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I looked at the repository on GitHub of qiskit terra (https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra) and in the examples they use BasicAer. So, I figure that they renamed to module.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! However, it seems that Qiskit is not guilty of this (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

The import error you're encountering, `ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit'`, is due to changes in the Qiskit package structure, particularly with the introduction of Qiskit 1.0. In Qiskit 1.0 and later versions, the import statement for `Aer` has been updated. Instead of importing `Aer` directly from `qiskit`, you should import it from `qiskit_aer`.

Here's how you can correctly import `Aer` in your code:

```py
from qiskit_aer import Aer
```

This change is reflected in the Qiskit 1.0 release notes and is mentioned in the provided sources. If you're using an older version of Qiskit, you might need to update your Qiskit installation to the latest version to use this import statement. You can update Qiskit using pip:

```bash
pip install --upgrade qiskit
```

Additionally, ensure that you have the `qiskit-aer` package installed, as it is required for using the Aer simulator. You can install it using pip:

```bash
pip install qiskit-aer
```

This should resolve the import error you're facing. Remember to update your import statements in your code to reflect these changes, especially if you're migrating from an older version of Qiskit to Qiskit 1.0 or later [2][3][4].

Comment: Base on Your comment on linux: from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, assemble

Answer (score 1):

To solve this try to import Aer separately. For example:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, execute, Aer, IBMQ
```

I hope this answers your question

Comment: How is this different than `from qiskit import Aer`?

Comment: It's the same thing but my version imports other things too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
from qiskit.providers.aer import Aer
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably problem between `pip install qiskit==0.27.0` and `conda install qiskit==0.27.0` that conda (or jupyter) cannot use qiskit which is installed in pip directly.
Therefore, I suggest you should reinstall in conda.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve it was installing qiskit-aer.

```
pip install qiskit qiskit-aer
```

And then import Aer thru it.

```
from qiskit_aer.aerprovider import AerSimulator
```